# Angular 4 Hide Dropdown on certain pages

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

I want to hide a Dropdown (it's elements included) on a certain page. I'd do it with a '*ngIf'-request, however I'm not sure about the condition.
The router path is '/project' but I can't access it - therefore *ngIf="path==='/project'" won't work.
Any ideas on what condition should be used? Or a better solution to the problem.

There also are subpaths like /project/id, on which the Dropdown should be available.

Comment: Dropdown  component is common for all component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your component/controller, try something like:

```
showDropdown: boolean = false;

ngOnInit() {
      this.showDropdown = path === '/project'
}
```

path is maybe a Input-variable of your component?

```
@Input
path: string;
```

In your HTML-Template, you do something like:

```
<div *ngIf="showDropdown">test</div>
```

Comment: It does not work with path like that (I mean path from the .route classes).

Comment: I really don't know what you mean, If you wanna have the route path, it depends on your used router.
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute) {
  console.log(route);
}
or 
constructor(private router:Router) {
  router.events.subscribe(...);
} should work for the standard router. There you can get the path of your url

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely right. I did the same and access the path with this.router.events.subscribe((val) => {
            this.path = this.location.path();
        }); 
in my constructor.
And in my html code: 
<li *ngIf="'path!==project'">...</li>.
But my page is broken now

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, add a boolean visible ( true or false )
and in you html simply add : *ngIf="visible" to your div

Comment: The dropdown exists in a navigationbar, and the project page is a different component.
I did add a boolean in my controller (main.component.ts) but where do I add the *ngIf now? 
The navbar at all is visible on every page. I just want to hide the dropdown on the project page.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your situation, you need to do the following:

- 1. In the navigation bar component you have to subscribe to routing to get the current path which will help you to realize whether show or not your dropdown, do the following

  `import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
  public showDropDown: boolean;
  constructor(private router: Router) {}
  ...
  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.showDropdown = event.url.indexOf('/project') >= 0;
      }
    }
  }`
- 2. In your html where your dropdown is present

  `<div class="my-dropdown" *ngIf="showDropdown">
     ... (your dropdown)
   </div>`

this will help you to avoid dependencies from other components and be able to manipulate data according to routing. Surely there will always be a way to improve this. Everything depends on what you want as a result.